# Can a chrome extension content script detect if it is running in iframe or top-level?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an extension which needs to manipulate the dom, including iframes, however I would like to do something a little different in case I'm in an iFrame.

How can the script detect if it is in the main page, or an iFrame?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, this is actually the same test you'd use in a standard web page:

```
if (window != window.top) {
  alert('In an IFRAME: ' + window.location.href);
}
```